# How do we remove RVM Default?

Tags: ruby, rvm, default

I have set my default RVM to ruby 1.9.2 . I want to remove this and keep it nil.

How can I do the same ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing any alias is as simple as:

```
rvm alias delete default
```

It's better to use it over `rm ~/.rvm/config/alias` suggested by @Sunny J. as it does additional cleaning steps.

It's also better than `rvm reset` as it only removes the alias, not resetting all rvm settings.

Comment: I'm Sunny J and I endorse this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/scripts/functions/reset

In order to remove your default without effecting your other settings in rvm,

```
rm ~/.rvm/config/alias
```

Modifying as necessary for your correct rvm path.

Answer (score 1):

See `rvm -h`:

```
reset       :: remove current and stored default & system settings.
```

So `rvm reset` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't want this to affect any other settings wrt rvm. Is there a way to do without affecting other rvm related settings?

Comment: I am sorry about.. but I would have to accept mpapis's answer and unaccept yours, as it meets all the requirements wrt what I want.. and for the benefit of anybody who might have a similar query going forward..Thanks for your answer.. I don't go with the user who has downvoted this answer though.. as it atleast was of some real help..